# no rows selected message when trying to run a sql command

Tags: sql, oracle

```
select first_name, last_name, accountID, balance
from customer c,  account a
where c.customer_ID = a.accountID;
```

with this this command i get a message which states "no rows selected"
someone please give guidance

Comment: well, then your join is probably failing.  Who knows,  you need to post a [mcve] with sample data.

Comment: It's unlikely that the account id should be joined to the customer id. Please include the full and complete table definitions, and refer to documents or colleagues that describe those tables and their use. There may also be a linking table in your schema that refers to both customers and accounts, look for that and include it in any update to your question.

Comment: Change it to `where c.customer_ID = a.customer_ID` maybe? Sample data would be helpful though, otherwise we are just guessing.

Answer (score 2):

There are either:

1. No rows in the `customer` table;
2. No rows in the `account` table; or
3. No rows where the `customer_ID` column of the `customer` table is equal to the `accountID` column of the `account` table.

You should check whether there are rows in the tables and whether it is appropriate to join the two tables on those two columns? Is it valid that you are checking if the identifier for an account matches the identifier for a customer?